# D3 Stack Line Chart

Tags: javascript, d3.js, charts, visualization

I'm working on a multi-line line chart in D3 (version 4) right now, and having some trouble. Here's what I am getting with my current code:

[image]

I think it has something to do with my x scale, but I can't figure out what is wrong. I've been following the tutorial [here](http://www.delimited.io/blog/2014/3/3/creating-multi-series-charts-in-d3-lines-bars-area-and-streamgraphs), with slight modifications because I am working with V4. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
 var parseDate = d3.timeParse("%Y");

var color = d3.scaleOrdinal(["#969FFD","#7173BF","#4B4C7F","#262640", "red"]);

var mySvg = d3.select("#chart8").append('svg')
   .attr('width', width + margin.right + margin.left)
   .attr('height', height + margin.bottom + margin.top)

var chartGroup = mySvg.append("g")
   .attr("class","fullGroup")
   .attr("transform", "translate("+margin.left+","+margin.top+")");

var parseDate = d3.timeParse("%Y");

d3.csv("../Assets/datasets/allDrugs3.csv", function(error, data){
if (error) throw error;

// FORMAT THE DATA //
var labelVar = "year";
var varNames = d3.keys(data[0]).slice(1);
    // Alternatively --> .filter(function(key){ return key !== labelVar;})
console.log(varNames); // <-- Names of drugs, used for color array

// Add color domain of names
color.domain(varNames);

var seriesData = varNames.map(function(name){
   return {
       name: name,
       values: data.map(function(d) {
            return { name: name, label: parseDate(d[labelVar]), value: +d[name]};
       })
   };
});

console.log(seriesData);

// Y-SCALE //

var yScale = d3.scaleLinear()
    .domain([
        d3.min(seriesData, function(c){ 
        return d3.min(c.values, function(d){ return d.value; });
        }), 
        d3.max(seriesData, function(c){
            return d3.max(c.values, function(d){ return d.value;});
        })
    ])
    .range([height, 0]);

console.log(
    "The y domain is",
    d3.min(seriesData, function(c){ 
        return d3.min(c.values, function(d){ return d.value; })}),
    "to", 
    d3.max(seriesData, function(c){
            return d3.max(c.values, function(d){ return d.value;});
        }));

// X-SCALE // 

var xYears = data.map(function(d){return parseDate(d.year);});    
var xScale = d3.scaleTime()
    .domain(xYears)
    .range([0, width]);

console.log(
    "The x domain is",
    xYears
)

var series = chartGroup.selectAll(".series")
    .data(seriesData)
    .enter().append("g")
        .attr("class","series");

var line = d3.line()
    .x(function(d){return xScale(d.label)})
    .y(function(d){return yScale(d.value); })
    .curve(d3.curveCardinal);

series.append("path")
    .attr("d", function(d){ return line(d.values); })
    .style("stroke", function (d) { return color(d.name); })
    .style("stroke-width", "4px")
    .style("fill", "none");

// Axes

var yAxis = d3.axisLeft(yScale).ticks(5).tickPadding(5);
var xAxis = d3.axisBottom(xScale).ticks(10);

chartGroup.append("g")
   .attr("class","Xaxis")
   .call(xAxis)
   .attr("transform","translate(0,"+height+")")
.selectAll("text")
    .style("text-anchor", "end")
    .attr("dx", "-.8em")
    .attr("dy", ".15em")
    .attr("transform", "rotate(-65)");

chartGroup.append("g")
    .attr("class","Yaxis")
    .call(yAxis)
    .selectAll("text")
    .style("text-anchor", "middle")
    .attr("dy", "-1em")
    .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)");
});
```

Here's the data:

```
key,deaths,year
heroin,289,2007
heroin,360,2008
heroin,238,2009
heroin,247,2010
heroin,392,2011
heroin,399,2012
heroin,464,2013
heroin,578,2014
heroin,748,2015
heroin,1212,2016
opiods,280,2007
opiods,251,2008
opiods,311,2009
opiods,342,2010
opiods,311,2011
opiods,302,2012
opiods,316,2013
opiods,330,2014
opiods,351,2015
opiods,418,2016
alchohol,175,2007
alchohol,162,2008
alchohol,160,2009
alchohol,161,2010
alchohol,195,2011
alchohol,187,2012
alchohol,238,2013
alchohol,270,2014
alchohol,310,2015
alchohol,582,2016
benzodiazepine,48,2007
benzodiazepine,52,2008
benzodiazepine,58,2009
benzodiazepine,68,2010
benzodiazepine,73,2011
benzodiazepine,37,2012
benzodiazepine,69,2013
benzodiazepine,103,2014
benzodiazepine,91,2015
benzodiazepine,126,2016
cocaine,157,2007
cocaine,162,2008
cocaine,135,2009
cocaine,148,2010
cocaine,153,2011
cocaine,248,2012
cocaine,154,2013
cocaine,198,2014
cocaine,221,2015
cocaine,463,2016
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a lot here, it might be easier just to post some working code. You idea is good, but there's a couple places it's breaking:

```
var varNames = d3.keys(data[0]).slice(1);
// Alternatively --> .filter(function(key){ return key !== labelVar;})
console.log(varNames); // <-- Names of drugs, used for color array
```

If you look at the console, you'll see this isn't giving you the drug names; it's giving you part of the first row of data, which isn't really useful.

For data in the format you have, one option is to use `d3.nest()`. This will take your array and give a new array grouped by the key of your choice. In this case we can group by drug like this:

```
 var nested = d3.nest()
    .key(d => d.key)
    .map(data)
```

Now `nested` will be an array of objects like:

```
[{alchohol: [{key: "alchohol", deaths: "175", year: "2007"},...}, 
 {benzodiazepine: [{key: "benzodiazepine", deaths: "48", year: "2007"}...
]
```

This makes the rest very natural. You can get the keys with `nested.keys()` and the arrays with `.entries()`

One thing to keep in mind with scales is that `d3.max()` returns the max in natural order — you need to to force the numerical order in the scale with `.domain([0 , d3.max(data, d => +d.deaths) ])`

Once that's all straightened out you can just pass `nested` into the `data()` function, and `.entries()` into your line generator and everything works pretty well.

Here's a working example that should help:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="d3/d3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="d3-selection-multi/d3-selection-multi.min.js"></script>
    <style>
    #chart div {
            background-color: steelblue;
            color: white;
            padding: 8px;
            text-align: right;
            margin:1px;
            font: 10px sans-serf
        }
        div#graphic {
            display: inline-block;
        /* border: 1px solid #333;*/
        }
        .title {
            fill: #666;
            font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
            text-anchor: middle;
            font-size: 24px;
        }
        .axis .domain, .axis .tick{
            stroke: #000;
            fill: none;
        }
        .bar {
            fill:steelblue;
            stroke: #444;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<div id ="chart"></div>
<div id="chart8"></div>
<button onclick="refresh()">refresh</button>
<script>
data = [{"key":"heroin","deaths":"289","year":"2007"},{"key":"heroin","deaths":"360","year":"2008"},{"key":"heroin","deaths":"238","year":"2009"},{"key":"heroin","deaths":"247","year":"2010"},{"key":"heroin","deaths":"392","year":"2011"},{"key":"heroin","deaths":"399","year":"2012"},{"key":"heroin","deaths":"464","year":"2013"},{"key":"heroin","deaths":"578","year":"2014"},{"key":"heroin","deaths":"748","year":"2015"},{"key":"heroin","deaths":"1212","year":"2016"},{"key":"opiods","deaths":"280","year":"2007"},{"key":"opiods","deaths":"251","year":"2008"},{"key":"opiods","deaths":"311","year":"2009"},{"key":"opiods","deaths":"342","year":"2010"},{"key":"opiods","deaths":"311","year":"2011"},{"key":"opiods","deaths":"302","year":"2012"},{"key":"opiods","deaths":"316","year":"2013"},{"key":"opiods","deaths":"330","year":"2014"},{"key":"opiods","deaths":"351","year":"2015"},{"key":"opiods","deaths":"418","year":"2016"},{"key":"alchohol","deaths":"175","year":"2007"},{"key":"alchohol","deaths":"162","year":"2008"},{"key":"alchohol","deaths":"160","year":"2009"},{"key":"alchohol","deaths":"161","year":"2010"},{"key":"alchohol","deaths":"195","year":"2011"},{"key":"alchohol","deaths":"187","year":"2012"},{"key":"alchohol","deaths":"238","year":"2013"},{"key":"alchohol","deaths":"270","year":"2014"},{"key":"alchohol","deaths":"310","year":"2015"},{"key":"alchohol","deaths":"582","year":"2016"},{"key":"benzodiazepine","deaths":"48","year":"2007"},{"key":"benzodiazepine","deaths":"52","year":"2008"},{"key":"benzodiazepine","deaths":"58","year":"2009"},{"key":"benzodiazepine","deaths":"68","year":"2010"},{"key":"benzodiazepine","deaths":"73","year":"2011"},{"key":"benzodiazepine","deaths":"37","year":"2012"},{"key":"benzodiazepine","deaths":"69","year":"2013"},{"key":"benzodiazepine","deaths":"103","year":"2014"},{"key":"benzodiazepine","deaths":"91","year":"2015"},{"key":"benzodiazepine","deaths":"126","year":"2016"},{"key":"cocaine","deaths":"157","year":"2007"},{"key":"cocaine","deaths":"162","year":"2008"},{"key":"cocaine","deaths":"135","year":"2009"},{"key":"cocaine","deaths":"148","year":"2010"},{"key":"cocaine","deaths":"153","year":"2011"},{"key":"cocaine","deaths":"248","year":"2012"},{"key":"cocaine","deaths":"154","year":"2013"},{"key":"cocaine","deaths":"198","year":"2014"},{"key":"cocaine","deaths":"221","year":"2015"},{"key":"cocaine","deaths":"463","year":"2016"}]

var margin = {
    top: 20,
    bottom: 20,
    left: 20,
    right: 20
}
var width = 800 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 600  - margin.top - margin.bottom

var parseDate = d3.timeParse("%Y");

var color = d3.scaleOrdinal(["#969FFD","#7173BF","#4B4C7F","#262640", "red"]);

var mySvg = d3.select("#chart8").append('svg')
.attr('width', width + margin.right + margin.left)
.attr('height', height + margin.bottom + margin.top)

var chartGroup = mySvg.append("g")
.attr("class","fullGroup")
.attr("transform", "translate("+margin.left+","+margin.top+")");

var parseDate = d3.timeParse("%Y");

d3.csv("./allDrugs3.csv", function(error, data){
    console.log(JSON.stringify(data))
    if (error) throw error;

    // FORMAT THE DATA //
    var nested = d3.nest()
        .key(d => d.key)
        .map(data)
    console.log("nest", nested.keys()) // <-- Names of drugs, used for color array
    console.log(nested) // <-- the actual data

    color.domain(nested);

    // Y-SCALE //
    var yScale = d3.scaleLinear()
        .domain([0 , d3.max(data, d => +d.deaths) ])
        .range([height, 0]);

    // X-SCALE // 
    var xScale = d3.scaleTime()
        .domain(d3.extent(data, d => d.year))
        .range([0, width])

    var line = d3.line()
        .x(d => xScale(d.year))
        .y(d => yScale(d.deaths))
        .curve(d3.curveCardinal);


    var series = chartGroup.selectAll(".series")
        .data(nested.entries())
        .enter().append("g")
            .attr("class","series")
        .append("path")
        .attr("d", d => {console.log(d); return line(d.value)})
        .style("stroke", function (d) { return color(d.key); })
        .style("stroke-width", "4px")
        .style("fill", "none");

    // Axes

    var yAxis = d3.axisLeft(yScale).ticks(5).tickPadding(5);
    var xAxis = d3.axisBottom(xScale).ticks(10);

    chartGroup.append("g")
    .attr("class","Xaxis")
    .call(xAxis)
    .attr("transform","translate(0,"+height+")")
    .selectAll("text")
        .style("text-anchor", "end")
        .attr("dx", "-.8em")
        .attr("dy", ".15em")
        .attr("transform", "rotate(-65)");

    chartGroup.append("g")
        .attr("class","Yaxis")
        .call(yAxis)
        .selectAll("text")
        .style("text-anchor", "middle")
        .attr("dy", "-1em")
        .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)");
});

</script>    
</body>
</html>
```